# Additional logical partition after 4 primary

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I've installed ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 and set up everything. Later, managed to spare more space from windows.

I want to use that space to extend root partition (\dev\sda3) and some create a logical partition for swap and add the rest to home partition(\dev\sda4). However, even if I boot with the install CD, GParted doesn't allow me to perform such action because there are already 4 primary partitions. Is there another way except for re-perform the complete installation?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owOX8.png)

Comment: I think you are using MBR. Then I don't think so. I am not sure though. Does your motherboard support GPT?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. But, I don't think it does